# How to present rows which can have several categories?

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data

I have a spreadsheet where the content is organized like that:

```
content  | category1 | category2 | category3 | ...
_________|___________|___________|___________| ...
content 1|     x     |           |     x     | ...
content 2|           |     x     |           | ...
...
```

How can I present this information more effectively? For example, is there a Javascript library I could use or something like that, where we could choose to show only the rows which are associated to some categories, or set a category to a row, etc?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on the platform/software you are using but in Excel you can do this with filters. Incidentally, this seems off-topic on this site, except if you tell us what you want to find out and expect some advice on how to visualize or analyze these data beyond merely filtering.

Comment: Agreed that the question, as it stands now, is a bit all over the place. The question does not principally seem to be about how the viz scheme drives analysis... though I think it could be edited to this end and salvage the question. Similarly, "setting" is more of a GUI / interactivity concept.

Answer (score -1):

Try http://datatables.net for a popular js grid-data framework with deep customizability.